# Get parent of a ListItem in a Google Docs file

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I'm trying to get the parent `ListItem` of a `ListItem` in a Google Doc. The `getParent()` function gets the parent element of the entire list (e.g. body), not the parent list item. 
So if I have:

- Parent list item

  - List item

For the "List item" element I want the returned parent to be the "Parent list item" element. The parent of "Parent list item" would be null.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you noticed, there's no method provided that does what you're looking for. So, you just need to put something together using the functionality that is provided.

Here's a quick attempt at implementing a function that given a list item returns the parent list item if found. Otherwise it returns `null` if a parent list item isn't found (i.e. a list that only consists of multiple-indented items) or if it's already at the top indent level.

```
function getParentListItem(listItem) {
  if (listItem.getType() != DocumentApp.ElementType.LIST_ITEM) {
    return null;
  }
  var currentNestingLevel = listItem.getNestingLevel();
  if (currentNestingLevel == 0) {
    return null;
  }
  var sibling = listItem.getPreviousSibling();
  while (sibling) {
    var siblingNestedLevel = sibling.getNestingLevel();
    if (siblingNestedLevel < currentNestingLevel) {
      return sibling;
    }
    sibling = sibling.getPreviousSibling();
  }
  return null;
}
```

I tested using a document with this content:

```
Not a list.
- Item 1
- Item 2
   - Nested Item 1
   - Nested Item 2
      - Double Nested Item 1
- Item 3
Not a list.
- List 2 Item 1
   - List 2 Nested Item 1
```

And using this function:

```
function test_getParentListItem() {
  var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
  for (var i = 0; i < body.getNumChildren(); i++) { 
    var child = body.getChild(i);
    if (child.getType() != DocumentApp.ElementType.LIST_ITEM) {
      Logger.log("Not a list item.");
      continue;
    }
    Logger.log("Looking up parent list item for: " + child.getText());
    var parentItem = getParentListItem(child);
    if (parentItem != null) {
      Logger.log("Parent list item: " + parentItem.getText());
    } else {
      Logger.log("No parent item found."); 
    }
  }
}
```

Which resulted in this log output:

```
[18-06-17 16:59:15:513 PDT] Not a list item
[18-06-17 16:59:15:515 PDT] Looking up parent list item for: Item 1
[18-06-17 16:59:15:516 PDT] No parent item found.
[18-06-17 16:59:15:518 PDT] Looking up parent list item for: Item 2
[18-06-17 16:59:15:519 PDT] No parent item found.
[18-06-17 16:59:15:524 PDT] Looking up parent list item for: Nested Item 1
[18-06-17 16:59:15:527 PDT] Parent list item: Item 2
[18-06-17 16:59:15:528 PDT] Looking up parent list item for: Nested Item 2
[18-06-17 16:59:15:531 PDT] Parent list item: Item 2
[18-06-17 16:59:15:533 PDT] Looking up parent list item for: Double Nested Item 1
[18-06-17 16:59:15:536 PDT] Parent list item: Nested Item 2
[18-06-17 16:59:15:538 PDT] Looking up parent list item for: Item 3
[18-06-17 16:59:15:539 PDT] No parent item found.
[18-06-17 16:59:15:541 PDT] Not a list item
[18-06-17 16:59:15:543 PDT] Looking up parent list item for: List 2 Item 1
[18-06-17 16:59:15:544 PDT] No parent item found.
[18-06-17 16:59:15:546 PDT] Looking up parent list item for: List 2 Nested Item 1
[18-06-17 16:59:15:549 PDT] Parent list item: List 2 Item 1
```

Comment: I thought of the same issue while out this afternoon and was working on a similar edit when I saw your suggested edit. Slightly modified your edit, added a similar check within the function itself and updated the example to be more thorough.